# Using jQuery UI tabs and jQuery UI selectmenu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I have two tabs and inside each of them I want to have some forms. I'm adding selectmenu, as well from jQuery UI inside each tab. The problem is that the select menu on the second tab won't show. I believe this has someting to do with how the tabs are loaded but I'm not quite sure how to solve it.

Here's the html code and a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/us8xbyyo/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI tabs</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./jQuery/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="./jQuery/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./jQuery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    $( ".mySelect" ).selectmenu();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Company</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Depto</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <label for="company">Company </label>
        <select class="mySelect" id ="company">
            <option value="-1">Chose a company</option>
            <option value="1">Company 1</option>
            <option value="2">Company 2</option>
            <option value="3">Company 3</option>
        </select>   
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <label for="depto">Depto</label>
        <select class="mySelect" id="depto" name="depto">
            <option value="-1">Chose a dpto</option>
            <option value="1">Dpto 1 </option>
            <option value="2">Dpto 2</option>
            <option value="3">Dpto 3</option>
        </select>   
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you could fix this problem by checking where your id name is for each drop-down div.

Your first div has the id="tabs-2" where it should be id="tabs-1".
Your second div has the id="tabs-1" where it should be id="tabs-2".

This way your links will now link to the correct div.

Secondly, I believe since you have the  tags already there in the HTML, it will automatically render as a dropdown with your options labeled in correspondence with whats between the  tabs.  Therefore, the jQuery for the .selectmenu is not needed, as well as the class name.

```
<body>
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Company</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Depto</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    <label for="company">Company </label>
    <select id="company">
        <option value="-1">Chose a company</option>
        <option value="1">Company 1</option>
        <option value="2">Company 2</option>
        <option value="3">Company 3</option>
    </select>   
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <label for="depto">Depto</label>
    <select id="depto">
        <option value="-1">Chose a depto</option>
        <option value="1">Dpto 1 </option>
        <option value="2">Dpto 2</option>
        <option value="3">Dpto 3</option>
    </select>   
</div>
```

```
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

This code seems to work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am aware the order in the <li> are switched but that is not the problem, the exaple above it's just an example of a more complex code. You just removed the selectmenu wich allowed the select to display, though this works to show the selects, they are not rendered using jQuery UI.

Comment: I believe you may need to have the jquery API loaded in.  Just calling the .selectmenu will not display anything.  You will need to pass in some parameters and properties for that function for it to do anything significant.  Hopefully this info will get you on the right track.  http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/  Remember, .selectmenu({  }); does not do anything by itself.

Answer (score 0):

So I followed @dcook advise and I looked into the documentation and decided to initialize `selectmenu()` with a particular width. Using Chrome's tools I was able to verify that the `selectmenu()` on the second tab was applied but the width was set to 0, wich is odd since the width should be automatically set depending on the length of the largest string inside the select.

Cheers.